# <input type="submit" /> prevents checkbox from being checked

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I might be missing something obvious here. I have a webpage that contains a form with a textbox and a checkbox.

The problem is that the checkbox can only be checked when `<%= Html.SubmitButton ...` is used as the submit button, but I want to use `<input type="submit ...` for the button but using this stops the user from being able to click the checkbox to make it checked.

What reasons could be causing this? Any suggestions for an alternative / things to try?

Note: this only happens in IE7.

**Edit:** The markup for the button is:

```
<input type="submit" value="<%=GetPlainText("testbutton", "test button")%>" />
```

However, I've discovered it works if I use the following - is there a way make it look like a default button? i.e must a css class be set for it?

```
<%= Html.SubmitButton("none").Value("test button") %>
```

Comment: Are you using JS / Jquery to submit the form? A bit of code around your problem would be useful to see. Please can you post it along with your question.

Comment: Fine but share the which does not work at least

Comment: You need to post your resulting HTML (that is, the HTML that you can see when you click 'View Source') and Javascript.

Comment: I've updated my orignial question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submit button will trigger a postback event and the check box checking wont happen.
use jquery to submit your form. Use a simple button and onclick call a javascript function

```
 <button class="gbtn" onclick="submituserEntry()">
                                    <span class="label">Submit</span>
                                </button>



function submituserEntry(){
 var ChangeReq = { "CurrentPassword": exstpwd, "NewPassword": newpwd }

                var jsondata = JSON.stringify(ChangeReq)
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "/myController/changeAction",
                    cache: false,
                    data: jsondata,
                    timeout: 10000,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (_results) {
                        alert(_results.Message);
                    },
                    error: function (_results) {
                    }
                });}
```

and in the controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult changeAction(passwordmodel _model)
    {
      String CurrentPassword=_model.CurrentPassword;
      String NewPassword= _model.NewPassword
      //do your stuff
      return View("Changesuccess");
     }
```